# Gtk# Themes, GTK-Wimp

Tags: c#

How do you use GTK-Wimp for Gtk# applications compiled in Windows? Or is it only for use on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

The theme engine wimp is only available for Windows. It's used by a theme called "MS-Windows" which is usually the default theme for Windows installations.